# My mom and dad are proud of me!

Tags: discussion, swag

It has been five years on Stack Overflow with you all. It's been a long journey, learning new things from the smartest people around the globe (and still am still learning!) and trying to contribute my knowledge in the best way I can to my fellow Stack Overflownians!!!

As a self-taught guy with no college certificates and no special certification courses opted for, this is a proud moment for me and my parents ha ha :p to get some swag from the best QA website for Programmers.

#### It's not a mug! It's a trophy.

---

I would like to thank many here without whom this was not possible. The Stack Overflow team for the swag, chat room friends who answered my foolish questions when I started Web Development, downvoters, who encouraged me to write better answers x) and thanks to the users who supported me by upvoting my answers.

I am aiming for 250k now (not coming anytime soon though :p)

[image: Stack Overflow Swag]

Comment: I am a simple kat. I see swag. I upvote.

Comment: I think I understand.  I now have new motivation to push for 100K+.  I could use a new mug; the one I have now has its font starting to rub off a wee bit.

Comment: "It's a major award"  (congrats)

Comment: Its a good thing!

Comment: Wow, yeah. Pretty cool. Looks like the swag has gotten a lot better over the years. We are all proud of you. :-)

Comment: If I ever get to 100k rep (who knows, maybe one day) then I want a mug that says `mug.fill('tea');` please! also, congrats @Mr.Alien, I couldn't agree more about how much SO has helped me too, here's to your 250k target!

Comment: When did SO start selling coffee mugs?

Comment: Wait. By looking at the emblem of the sticker, you must be a time traveler. Congrats!

Comment: So what happens at 250k? A portrait of unicorns?

Comment: It would be interesting to calculate the cost of the mug as a percentage of revenues and/or market cap attributable to your activities.

Comment: @DavidG - careful, you might get [419 - i'm a coffeepot](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2324#section-2.3.2) :)

Comment: @EliranMalka Well [possibly not for much longer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_Text_Coffee_Pot_Control_Protocol#Save_418_Movement)

Comment: I barely ever drink the entire mug to leave it 'empty', does that mean I'll never enter into that if?

Comment: Man I want that mug

Comment: Congrats @Mr.Alien =)

Comment: Congrats buddy!

Comment: It's awesome seeing another person like me. Like you, I've never taken a class but taught myself everything (with help of SO of course). I've been on this site since I was 14. I'm really excited to see this post. I haven't written recently because I felt discouraged with plagiarism, criticism, and other things but this post officially made SO apart of my summer bucket list again XD . I'm really grateful to this community for helping me further my knowledge and interest in computer programming. I recall seeing in the yearly reports that teens make up less than 2.5% of users.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Remember when you first started out and you disliked how critical I was of your answers and how I was seemingly following you around [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)[css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) and having something to say every time?

Yeah, those were fun times.

Congrats!

Comment: And the crowd yells: *fight!, fight!, fight!* ...

Comment: Haha yes I do remember.. lot of rage comments from me : p realized it later that you helping me out.. sry .. and to be honest, I was going to mention few of you guys.. but they are too many  :p  and thanks bud!

Comment: *wipes tear* And they all lived SO happily ever after.

Comment: @Mr.Alien It wasn't just you. BoltClock harasses everyone who posts in the html and css tags. ;p

Comment: @BilltheLizard Need a "Report User" option on profiles now `feature-request` x0

Answer (score 29):

Congratulations!

I'm nowhere near 100k yet. However, two amazing things happened to me today:

1. I wrote my 1000th answer, and
2. I hit 20k

So, I can understand the sense of accomplishment you must be feeling.

I first registered as a user a little over 2 years ago, but began seriously answering questions only around 2 to 2 and a half months ago. Until then, I had been using the SE network for assistance with homework and assignments. One day, I asked a question, and then as I was waiting for someone to answer, I saw *another* question in the Python tag, and I thought to myself: *Hey, I can answer this!* And I never stopped since then.

Answering questions has done two things for me. It has helped me teach a lot of people who know lesser than me, but more importantly, it has helped me learn a lot *more* from people who know more than me. I would daresay answering questions on a particular tag is as effective as taking a full blown course at a reputed university on the same subject.

Another thing I'd like to mention: I love the community on SO. It is frank, honest, and pushes you to do better, and also to be better than you currently are. I would've learned a lot less if not for all the downvotes I've received over the weeks.

You've touched nearly 10 million people in your time here. That is a phenomenal number, and it is only going to increase.

Sorry, this has become longer than I wanted it to be. But to wrap up, here's to another 5 years of being a valuable member of the community!

All the best.

Comment: Yeah, dude, I've been watching you race towards infinity since when you started earning tons of rep and wondering how the heck can you earn rep with such immense speed. Looks like you're not too far away from getting your own SO mug :D

Comment: I know that feeling. When I started, I tried to answer questions. When I couldn't, I used to wait for someone else to answer and learn from that. I would 've worked as a financial consultant if it was not StackOverflow. Thank you for appreciating, it means a lot. All the best to you too :)

Comment: you have been absolutely rocketing by with some really solid answers. Keep it up!

Comment: @Mr.Alien Fun times, Mr Alien, fun times... :-)

Comment: @coldspeed congratulations :D